# How to make Regexs only match on exact-matches?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, exact-match

Ok, so basically I have some bit of code that matches URLs by regexs. It then will call some function based on which regex the URL matches against. I never want for more than one function to be called for a URL and I want the regex matches to have to be "exact"

For instance, with the simple URL `/` I use a simple regex `/` which will match `/` but it will also match things like `/foo` and `/foo/bar`.

How can I prevent this partial matching behavior in C#/.Net?

Comment: Have you tried using .NET URL Routing instead of rolling your own route dispatcher?

Comment: @JacobKrall funny you should have mentioned that. I went on to implement my own URL routing(in a much more standalone fashion than .Net's) method like a month after this question :P

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `^` for matching the start of a string and `$` for the end of a string.

For example: `^/$` matches `/` but not `/foo`. And `^/` matches `/foo` but not `foo/`.

Comment: Hmm. I had to change around a few regexs to work with this, but this seems to be the answer. I wasn't sure it was possible to do this only be slightly modifying the regular expressions

Answer (score -3):

Append space at start and end of keyword you want to match with. 
For example you have a string `"Hey! foobar I am foo bar."` Now lets say you want to match foo. 
You can do this `/\s+foo\s+/i` this will return match for only foo and not foobar.

Comment: This doesn't work if the word is the first the string or last in a sentence or the string.